# AWS lambda edit html template with data from DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to insert data retrieved from a DynamoDB database into an HTML template that is being stored on S3 (filling in the blanks on an HTML form, essentially).  I am not very proficient in JavaScript, so I'm not really sure where to start.

So far, I've been able to retrieve the HTML document from S3 and convert to UTF8 string...which is maybe not necessary but I was just practicing talking to S3 with Lambda.

Do I need to use a third-party library in order to have the HTML contain variables I can change?  Or can I just change the inner HTML of ID'd ref's somehow?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The main goal here is taking user input (stored on DynamoDB), filling in the blanks on the HTML form, and converting the HTML into a PDF document.

If anyone can think of a better way to add user input to a text template and then convert that into a PDF, I am open to any suggestions!

Thanks

Comment: Re-writing a static page is far from ideal, but if it's your only option then you could consider writing the DynamoDB data into a JSON file in S3 and have your mainline HTML/JS read from that JSON file at runtime and render the table or whatever visual elements you want to visualize the data.

Comment: @jarmod I should note that the only reason I am using HTML is because my end-goal is to convert the html into a pdf document. (Updated question).  I will give your idea a try, though, it does sound promising. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case it would be more structured and maintainable to use a lightweight HTML templating library.

For example using [Lodash.js](https://lodash.com/docs#template) you can do the following.

```
_.template([string=''], [options={}])
```

In here you can define the variables in the html file with following markup and then read the file content and bind with the data retrieved from DynamoDB as options to return the final HTML string which you can save back to a file in S3.

```
<div>
    <h1>My name is <%- name %></h1>
    <p>I like <%- hobbies %> but hate being a <%- occupation %></p> 
</div>

var filledHTML = _.template("HTML string'', { name: "John", hobbies: "Reading", occupation: "developer"})
```

Note: Use the [lodash.template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.template) npm for your lambda.

```
npm i --save lodash.template
```

Comment: I was looking into using EJS but I wasn't sure if templating was the way to go until I read your comment. I will look into Lodash as well.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: For the record, I ended up using Lodash. The lambda function, using an even shorter html string than in your example, took almost 4 seconds...  If I'm going to be batching this and filling out a lot of templates, I may need to re-think my approach.  And check my bank account.

Comment: This is mainly for the host start. Did you check the subsequent requests? Does it take the same amount of time? Also try increasing the memory and see whether it goes below 1 second.